# SwiftUI TextField with ViewModel not working

Tags: swiftui, textfield, viewmodel, property-wrapper-published

For a personal project, I am trying to set up an app according MVVM with Aviation Weather Data. I have a SearchBarView with a connected SearchBarViewModel. In this SearchBarViewModel, there is only one @Published var which is the Airport code (Two-way binded with the SearchBarView). I want to share this property with a class to make a network request. It seems that there is something wrong between the SearchBarView and the SearchBarViewModel, but I cannot find the problem...

```
import SwiftUI

struct SearchBarView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = SearchBarViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button {
                //Locate nearest airport with CoreLocation.
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "location.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
            }
            
            TextField("Enter ICAO Code", text: $viewModel.airportCode)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .padding(.vertical, 8)
                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                .cornerRadius(10)
        }
    }
}

------------------------------------

import Foundation
import SwiftUI

final class SearchBarViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var airportCode = ""
}
```

When I type something in the TextField in the ContentView, The SearchBarViewModel is not "updated" and does not publish anything...`

Comment: You should be using StateObject not ObservedObject

Comment: Your code works properly, and the `airportCode` gets updated by changing the TextField.

Comment: Every time you call SearchBarViewModel() you create a different instance, one does not know about the other

Comment: If you really must to use a `ObservableObject` class for some reason, then have a look at this  **official** link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app:  [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app) .
Also (recommended) look at using `@State var airportCode = ""` in the parent `View`, and `@Binding var airportCode: String` in your `SearchBarView` passing it using `SearchBarView(airportCode: $airportCode)` 
instead of the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SwiftUI is already MVVM you don't need your own objects, that is what `@State` is for. So it's just:

```
struct SearchBarView: View {
    @State var airportCode = ""
```

SwiftUI will take your hierarchy of `View` data structs, diff it, then use the difference in the data to generate the `V` layer automatically for you choosing the best UIKit, AppKit etc. objects depending on the platform/context.

When passing data down to child Views - pass down `let` for read access or `@Binding var` for read/write. In both cases `body` is called when the values change, think of `body` like an "onChange". The result is then diffed.

You can put your funcs for logic anywhere you like and make them return values you set on `@State`. Or you can group vars together into a custom struct and add a mutating func there. But since this is Swift just try to avoid classes when you can or you'll run into consistency issues/memory leaks since its tricky to get right, as you experienced.